# How to raise a different kind of error when an error occurs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, exception

I'm wondering how I would go about setting up a way to raise a **RuntimeError** when I know a **ValueError** will occur in my code. For example:

```
def example(string):
    try:
       var1, var2, var3 = string.split(":")
    except ValueError:
       raise RuntimeError
```

If I input a string with less than 3 elements seperated by colons (i.e "Hi:SO!") I will expect to get a ValueError; however I want to have this raise a RuntimeError instead and continue on with the program without grinding it to a halt. How would I go about raising this ValueError as a RuntimeError while still excepting the RuntimeError?

Comment: This *does* raise a RuntimeError (after you indent the assignment and fix the name `var 3` to `var3`). The real question is *why* would you want to raise the specific exception? Exceptions have a purprose: to inform a user about why something bad happened.

Comment: You seem to be doing it right! Just use another try if you really want to "Catch" a runtime error!

Comment: Thank you, I tried the second try method and it worked perfectly!

Comment: If you want to continue the execution of the program after catching an Exception, you can use Warnings instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
vars = string.split(":")
if not len(vars) == 3:
    raise RuntimeError("your message")
else:
    var1, var2, var3 = vars
```

The idea is to check if the string split list length is equal to 3 and if yes you raise whatever exception you want and you handle it where you want after that (with the appropriate exception handling).